# How to not scale CATextLayers when scaling super layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, catextlayer

My problem is:

I have a `CAShapeLayer` named `outCircle`. I add some `CATextLayers` as sublayers of `outCircle`. The problem is that when I'm pinching `outCircle` and doing so scale it, the sublayer `CATextLayers` resize too (maybe obvious) and become blurry and not crisp. The text looks horrible!

So **I want to keep the original size and (maybe) position of the text layers yet keeping them sublayers of `outCircle`**.

- Is it possible?
- How can I do it?

One solution is to not make the `CATextLayers` sublayers of `outCircle` but for various reasons I need to do it. Thanks for your help in advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting the inverse-scale value to textLayers.
i.e if you set scale of .5 to shapeLayer, set (1/.5 =2) as scale to textLayers.

```
shapeLayer.affineTransform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5, .5);
textLayer.affineTransform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
```

Comment: note: you can't keep a sublayer unscaled when you scale super so inverse-scaling sounds like a good option

Comment: inverse of 0.5 is 2.0, not 1.5